# Unable to move my mouse to second screen Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

I'm having a huge issue with Windows 8, although I had no problem with Windows 7. I have my second screen connected and extended, however when I move the mouse to the right it will NOT go to the second screen like it used to do in Windows 7. Now it opens that Windows 8 Option thingy.

How do I fix this?

Comment: if you move it to the other side does it go to the 2nd screen?

Comment: lol it does, why is it doing to left instead of the right? , it used to be vice versa

EDIT: nvm, swaped it in the config and works now, ty :).

Answer (score 15):

You displays are not ordered correctly.  Right click on the Desktop background and go to Screen Resolution.  You can then drag and drop the monitors into the right locations.

Comment: Yup, just reverse the numbering of your screens.

Comment: And when the displays are of different resolutions, you may want to align them correctly as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by changing the output of the extended screen to:

- Digital Display + Built-in Display

[image: Output (To) the extended desktop with Digital Display + Built-in Display]

Blog: http://ask.osify.com/qa/653

Answer (score 0):

I suffered briefly from the same problem and followed user Keltari's  answer above, upon which I thought to enlarge now. I didn't see  OSIFY's answer until I had already fixed the solution.

In my case, my 2nd screen was physically positioned to the left of the first. Yet somewhy, in Screen Resolution, the computer assumed the 2nd screen to be to the RIGHT, wrongly. Once I dragged the 2nd screen back to the left of the first, the problem was solved.